# Does the GraphQL#execute run all DataFetchers on the same thread? Is the asynchronous behaviour delegated to the DataFetcher implementation?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

If all my Data Fetchers returned POJOs directly instead of CompletableFuture, will the entire GraphQL execution happen on the same thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Based on what I see from the source codes , if all data fetchers only return POJO, the whole execution will execute on the same thread.

To configure data fetchers to run in parallel , you have to use the `ExecutionStrategy` that supports asynchronous processing. The default one used by the query (`AsyncExecutionStrategy`) supports while the mutation (`AsyncSerialExecutionStrategy`) does not.

The data fetcher also has to return a `CompletableFuture` using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`. Please note that `graphql-java` provides a handy data fetcher called `AsyncDataFetcher` which can wrap a normal synchronous data fetcher to the asynchronous one:

```
DataFetcher asyncDataFetcher = AsyncDataFetcher.async(fooDataFetcher);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had asked this in the spectrum chat for GraphQL Java and had gotten the same answer from the officials devs: https://spectrum.chat/graphql-java/general/does-the-graphql-object-execute-on-a-single-thread-is-the-asynchronous-behavior-delegated-to-the-datafetcher-implementation~d4704359-f30a-4e85-a36a-0b1234d3f5c2. Posting link so someone looking at this can have greater confidence in the answer.